# Data type mapping for unsigned short* to VB .net using DLLImport

Tags: .net, vb.net, dll, dllimport, function-calls

I can call my 64-bit C-style dll by using DLLImport

Header file

```
typedef long long PHI_INT;
PHI_STATUS PHI_EXP_CONV PHI_LibraryInitialize(PHI_64 init_settings = PHI_NULL);
```

In VB .net

```
<DllImport("PhiOpticsSDK.dll")>
Private Shared Function PHI_LibraryInitialize(ByVal init_settings As IntPtr) As IntPtr
End Function
```

Does anybody know what datatype `unsigned short*` maps to? Was thinking `IntPtr`but that's the wrong size..

```
PHI_STATUS PHI_EXP_CONV PHI_ComputePush(const unsigned short* ptr_in, PHI_64 rows, PHI_64 cols, PHI_64 pattern, PHI_64 timeout_ms, float background_offset = 0.0f);
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be UShort, this website is a good way of checking them http://www.marvintest.com/knowledgebase/KBArticle.aspx?ID=210

Comment: There's no such thing as a `UShort*`. VB.NET doesn't support raw pointers.

Answer (score 0):

An `IntPtr` should be sufficient if used correctly. The size doesn't matter because the `IntPtr` is used as a ***memory pointer***, meaning it merely points to a location in memory. It isn't supposed hold an actual value, so you can't just assign it a number of type `UShort` and expect it to work.

However, if I am not mistaken, you should also be able to declare it as a `ByRef` `UShort` (`ByRef` standing for *By Reference*), meaning the method now expects a `UShort`'s ***reference pointer*** (i.e. the pointer to its memory location) just like the C function.

The declaration would look something like this:

```
Private Shared Function PHI_ComputePush(ByRef ptr_in As UShort, ...
```

---

**EDIT:**

A quick and dirty solution using `IntPtr`, just for reference:

```
'Replace "Number" with your actual variable.
Dim Number As UShort = 35846
Dim Handle As GCHandle

Try
    Handle = GCHandle.Alloc(Number, GCHandleType.Pinned)

    'Gets the memory address of the "Number" variable.
    Dim Ptr As IntPtr = Handle.AddrOfPinnedObject()

    PHI_ComputePush(Ptr, ...your parameters here...)
Finally
    'Releases the GCHandle so that our "Number" variable can be collected by the GC (Garbage Collector) when the time comes.
    If Handle.IsAllocated = True Then Handle.Free()
End Try
```

Comment: Does the that declaration support passing arrays? For example pass something like `dim square_of_data(512,512) As UShort`

Comment: @Mikhail : The `IntPtr` version perhaps, though I'm not sure that the marshaller supports 2D arrays. It may only work with jagged arrays. How are you using `ptr_in` anyway?

Comment: @Mikhail : Anything that is a pointer is usually mapped to either `IntPtr`, the variable declared as `ByRef`, or a 1D array of the data type. Unfortunately I've never marshalled 2D arrays so I'm not sure. If possible please show a use case.

Comment: @Mikhail : Any progress with this?